# Google Play Services issue loadPlayerCenteredScores method doesn't return circles scores if COLLECTION_SOCIAL specified

Tags: android, google-play-services

We're attempting to get scores of players that are in current player's circles using the Google Game Services API GamesClient.loadPlayerCenteredScores() method.

This is the invocation code:

`loadPlayerCenteredScores(listener, mLeaderboardId,              LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME, LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_SOCIAL, 25, true);`

- Note we're using **LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_SOCIAL**  with the assumption this would retrieve
  scores of players that are in the circles of current player

The actual resulti s that we're getting a buffer that has only one score entry, of the current player.

Anyone has any pointers regarding this matter?
Maybe anyone from Google whose reading?

We're really baffled, as LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC returns everything, but the whole
list, if traversed wholly, might be huge.

Thanks, Max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the reason we haven't seen scores of friends in our circles.

You must *Publish* the game in the Game Service dashboard in Google Play Console, it wasn't enough that
the game was in "Ready To Test" state, and the relevant tester emails were written in the Testing pane.

It might be a bug introduced not long ago, because we did see it work.

I hope this helps anyone encounters the same issue.

Cheers, Max